# Why is こんばんみ used as a response to こんばんは？

Tags: meaning, words, hiragana

When I chat the term こんばんみ is occasionally used as a response to こんばんは. Is there any particular reason why this word is chosen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

「こんばん**み**」 is a greeting presumably created and definitely made popular by [comedian ビビる大木](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibiru_%C5%8Cki) a couple of decades ago.

As always, some people like to mimic whatever schtick they hear on TV that they find "cool" or simply "new".

「こんばんみ」 was even more popular a decade or two ago than it is now.  I was a bit surprised to hear you still hear/see it often enough.

[Here](https://ameblo.jp/bibiruooki/) is the top page of Ooki's official blogs and you already know what he says at the very beginning!

Comment: Is it a play on how things sound, and then reinterpreting?  今晩は → //konban wa// → 今晩​我【わ】 → 我【わ】 = "me", substitute → 今晩ミー?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I don't know Japanese, but isnt' 我(わ) too archaic?

Comment: @Akangka, define "too".  For the purposes of a dumb joke (and from the perspective of someone who is very prone to making 親父ギャグ), everything the audience might be aware of is on the table.  :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi so it's not too archaic, then.